# I have installed the french language pack for Sonarqube, but I don't know how to change the default language

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I'm new to Sonarqube, In order to Localization, I installed the French plugin from Marketplace, but I don't know how to change the default language of seven version of Sonarqube.
Is it possible to guide me?

Comment: did you go through this [Internationalization](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Internationalization), it might help?

Comment: By setting add-on on a browser, I can solve the problem.